# Melting of 2 circular ponds after winter

Tags: water, thermal-conduction

Two circular ponds of equal depth have various diameter. Both ponds are situated not far from each other and are subject to the same winter conditions. When the spring comes, the ice cap starts melting. Which one of the 2 ponds is going to become open water earlier: the bigger or the smaller? Why?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule the smaller pond will both freeze more quickly and thaw more quickly since it has a smaller heat capacity. Puddles freeze and thaw more quickly than lakes. However, there are many different variables that may affect the rate of freezing and thawing in any specific case.

Comment: well, every year I observe the opposite picture in my neighborhood ;) Although puddles do happen to melt faster, they ain't as deep as ponds